# Voice Note is reset/ recreated while playing, after Chat Page is rebuilt

Tags: flutter, audio-streaming, bloc, just-audio

I made a Chat app and used just_audio to replay voice note attachment in chat page.
While playing voice note, if a new message is sent or received and showed up on page, the audio player is reset.
I found out the reason is that, the whole chat page which include audio message widget were rebuilt everytime a new message is sent or received.

This is my _ChatMessages class. It is managed with BLOC.

```
class _ChatMessages extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ChatMessages({
    required this.messageScrollController,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ItemScrollController messageScrollController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ChatPageCubit, ChatPageState>(
      builder: (context, state) => StreamMessageListView(
        messageFilter: (msg) {
          final filter = state.filter?.type;
          switch (filter) {
            case null:
              return true;
            case MessageFilterType.confirmations:
              return msg.extraData['customType'] == 'CONFIRM_REQUEST';
            case MessageFilterType.files:
              return msg.attachments.any((a) => a.type == 'file');
            case MessageFilterType.images:
              return msg.attachments.any(
                (a) => a.type == 'image' && (a.ogScrapeUrl?.isEmpty ?? true),
              );
            case MessageFilterType.pinned:
              return msg.pinned;
            case MessageFilterType.polls:
              return msg.extraData['customType'] == 'POLL';
            case MessageFilterType.videos:
              return msg.attachments.any((a) => a.type == 'video');
            case MessageFilterType.voice:
              return msg.attachments.any((a) => a.type == 'voicenote');
            default:
              return true;
          }
        },
        scrollController: messageScrollController,
        headerBuilder: (_) => const SizedBox(height: 80),
        onMessageSwiped: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
        showFloatingDateDivider: false,
        messageBuilder: ((ctx, msg, list, messageWidget) {
          final key = Key('Message-${msg.message.id}');
          // debugPrint('messages built');
          if (!msg.message.isDeleted) {
            try {
              if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] == 'TEAM_JOINED') {
                return TeamJoinedMessage(key: key, message: msg.message);
              } else if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] == 'CALL') {
                return CallMessage(
                  key: key,
                  message: msg.message,
                  isMyMessage: msg.isMyMessage,
                );
              } else if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] ==
                  'CONFIRM_REQUEST') {
                return _ConfirmationMessage(
                  key: key,
                  messageDetails: msg,
                  userId: StreamChat.of(context).currentUser?.id ?? '',
                  onReplyTap: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
                );
              } else if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] ==
                  'EVENT_INVITE') {
                return _EventInviteMessage(
                  key: key,
                  message: msg.message,
                  isMyMessage: msg.isMyMessage,
                  onReplyTap: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
                );
              } else if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] ==
                  'HIGH_PRIORITY') {
                return _HighPriorityMessage(
                  key: key,
                  message: msg.message,
                  isMyMessage: msg.isMyMessage,
                  onReplyTap: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
                );
              } else if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] == 'TEAM_INVITE') {
                return _TeamInviteMessage(
                  key: key,
                  message: msg.message,
                  isMyMessage: msg.isMyMessage,
                  onReplyTap: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
                );
              } else if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] == 'POLL') {
                return _PollMessage(
                  key: key,
                  messageDetails: msg,
                  userId: StreamChat.of(context).currentUser?.id ?? '',
                  onReplyTap: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
                );
              } else if (msg.message.extraData['customType'] == 'RECORDING') {
                return _RecordingMessage(
                  key: key,
                  messageDetails: msg,
                  onReplyTap: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
                );
              }
            } catch (_) {}
          }
          // debugPrint('voice note built 2');
          return messageWidget.copyWith(
            key: key,
            showPinButton: state.canPinMessages,
            customAttachmentBuilders: {
              'tenor': gifAttachmentBuilder,
              'voicenote': (context, message, attachments) =>
                  voiceAttachmentBuilder(
                    context,
                    message,
                    attachments,
                    msg.isMyMessage,
                  ),
            },
            customActions: [
              StreamMessageAction(
                leading: Image.asset(Assets.icShare, height: 28, width: 28),
                title: Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.share,
                  style: StreamChatTheme.of(context).textTheme.body,
                ),
                onTap: (message) => openChatShareDialog(
                  context,
                  message.text,
                  enableExternalSharing: true,
                  hideTextInput: true,
                  streamMessage: message,
                ),
              )
            ],
            onAttachmentTap: !kIsWeb && Platform.isAndroid
                ? (message, attachment) {
                    mediaAttachmentPageBuilder(
                      context,
                      messageWidget,
                      message,
                      attachment,
                    );
                  }
                : null,
            onReplyTap: context.read<ChatInputCubit>().reply,
            bottomRowBuilderWithDefaultWidget:
                (context, message, defaultWidget) {
              MessageMetaInfo? meta;
              try {
                meta = MessageMetaInfo.fromJson(
                  message.extraData['meta'] as Map<String, dynamic>,
                );
              } catch (_) {}
              if (!msg.isMyMessage) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(child: defaultWidget),
                    if (!message.isDeleted &&
                        (meta?.entities.isNotEmpty ?? false)) ...[
                      const SizedBox(width: 8),
                      AIPrompts(entities: meta!.entities),
                    ],
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                final channel = StreamChannel.of(context).channel;

                return Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    if (!message.isDeleted &&
                        (meta?.entities.isNotEmpty ?? false)) ...[
                      AIPrompts(entities: meta!.entities),
                      const SizedBox(width: 8),
                    ],
                    Text(
                      Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(message.createdAt.toLocal()).jm,
                      style: StreamChatTheme.of(context)
                          .ownMessageTheme
                          .createdAtStyle,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 4),
                    BetterStreamBuilder<List<Read>>(
                      stream: channel.state?.readStream,
                      initialData: channel.state?.read,
                      builder: (context, data) {
                        final readList = data.where((it) =>
                            it.user.id !=
                                StreamChat.of(context).currentUser?.id &&
                            (it.lastRead.isAfter(message.createdAt) ||
                                it.lastRead
                                    .isAtSameMomentAs(message.createdAt)));
                        final isMessageRead =
                            readList.length >= (channel.memberCount ?? 0) - 1;
                        Widget child = StreamSendingIndicator(
                          message: message,
                          isMessageRead: isMessageRead,
                          size: 18,
                        );
                        if (isMessageRead) {
                          child = Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              if (channel.memberCount! > 2)
                                Text(
                                  readList.length.toString(),
                                  style: StreamChatTheme.of(context)
                                      .ownMessageTheme
                                      .createdAtStyle
                                      ?.copyWith(
                                        color: StreamChatTheme.of(context)
                                            .colorTheme
                                            .accentPrimary,
                                      ),
                                ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 2),
                              child,
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                        return child;
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }
            },
          );
        }),
        emptyBuilder: (_) => const Center(
          child: IllustrationImage(
            assetName: Assets.imgEmptyChats,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is Voice Attachment Builder. I followed exactly the tutorial.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:stream_chat_flutter/stream_chat_flutter.dart';
import '../../../../../constants/colors.dart';

/// Builds Voice Message Playback & Loading attachment for voice messages.
///
/// Credits: https://github.com/HayesGordon/stream-audio-attachment-tutorial
Widget voiceAttachmentBuilder(
  BuildContext context,
  Message defaultMessage,
  List<Attachment> attachments,
  bool isMyMessage,
) {
  try {
    final url = attachments.first.assetUrl;
    late final Widget widget;

    if (url == null) {
      widget = const AudioLoadingMessage();
    } else {
      widget = _AudioPlayerMessage(
        source: AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(url)),
        id: defaultMessage.id,
        isMyMessage: isMyMessage,
      );
    }
    return SizedBox(
      key: Key('VoiceMessage-${defaultMessage.id}'),
      width: 250,
      height: 50,
      child: widget,
    );
  } catch (_) {}

  return const Offstage();
}

class AudioLoadingMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AudioLoadingMessage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 3,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.mic),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _AudioPlayerMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _AudioPlayerMessage({
    required this.source,
    required this.id,
    required this.isMyMessage,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final AudioSource source;
  final String id;
  final bool isMyMessage;

  @override
  _AudioPlayerMessageState createState() => _AudioPlayerMessageState();
}

class _AudioPlayerMessageState extends State<_AudioPlayerMessage> {
  final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  late StreamSubscription<PlayerState> _playerStateChangedSubscription;

  late Future<Duration?> futureDuration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _playerStateChangedSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen(playerStateListener);

    futureDuration = _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(widget.source);
  }

  void playerStateListener(PlayerState state) async {
    if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
      await reset();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _playerStateChangedSubscription.cancel();
    _audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Duration?>(
      future: futureDuration,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              _controlButtons(),
              _slider(snapshot.data),
            ],
          );
        }
        return const AudioLoadingMessage();
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _controlButtons() {
    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
      stream: _audioPlayer.playingStream,
      builder: (context, _) {
        final color = _audioPlayer.playerState.playing
            ? Colors.amber
            : widget.isMyMessage
                ? Colors.white
                : TimeeColors.dullBlack;
        final icon =
            _audioPlayer.playerState.playing ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow;
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (_audioPlayer.playerState.playing) {
                pause();
              } else {
                play();
              }
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              child: Icon(icon, color: color, size: 30),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _slider(Duration? duration) {
    return StreamBuilder<Duration>(
      stream: _audioPlayer.positionStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && duration != null) {
          return Slider(
            activeColor:
                widget.isMyMessage ? Colors.white : TimeeColors.dullBlackOpaque,
            inactiveColor: widget.isMyMessage
                ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4)
                : TimeeColors.dullBlack.withOpacity(0.4),
            value: snapshot.data!.inMicroseconds / duration.inMicroseconds,
            onChanged: (val) {
              _audioPlayer.seek(duration * val);
            },
          );
        } else {
          return const SizedBox.shrink();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> play() {
    return _audioPlayer.play();
  }

  Future<void> pause() {
    return _audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  Future<void> reset() async {
    await _audioPlayer.stop();
    return _audioPlayer.seek(const Duration(milliseconds: 0));
  }
}
```

I tried to used AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to keep the audio player alive, but it had no effect.
Also the methode didUpdateWidget was used, but it couldn't help. I don't know if I was missing sth.

It's a big help if anyone could help me to figure out a solution without changing the main structure and without switching BLOC. Should I use BLOC for Audio Player or should I prevent BLOC from unneccessary Rebuild and how?